# Загруженный файл не появляется в системной папке загрузки

Tags: java, android, файлы

Получаю изображение по средствам сокетов. Изображение появляется в галерее, потому что системе сообщили о новом файле строкой:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
```

Но мне необходимо чтобы пользователь мог получить доступ к файлу (.txt , .pdf , .doc и др форматов) без каких- либо файловых менеджеров. Файл должен появиться в системной папке загрузки, но он не появляется. Опыт с галерей был такой же пока не добавил ту строку. Как сообщить системе о новом файле для того чтобы к нему можно обратиться через папку загрузки? Возможно существует другой способ. Заранее благодарю и надеюсь на конструктивные ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Надо выгрузку делать через системный сервис [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) - тогда он появится в папке загрузок, иначе он там не появится.

Comment: Как быть с тем, (1) что файл уже получен и (2) для использования DownloadManager необходимо Uri (DownloadManager.Request(Uri uri)) ? P.s файл получаем не по адресу сервера в сети, а по ip-адресу(локальному) устройства другого и порта передачи.